# Group Decomposition via the Centralizer of an element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $g$ is an element of a group $G$.

The centralizer of $g$ (set of elements of $G$ commuting with $g$) is a subgroup, call it $H$.

Is there ever a decomposition of $G$ as a direct sum of groups with $H$ being one of them?

Comment: Did you try any examples at all?

Comment: There is never such a decomposition, and you should be able to prove it yourself.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, never a non-trivial one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is never (excluding the case $G=H$.)
Here is a case where it is not true. Let $G=S_3$ and $h= (123)$ then $H=\langle (123) \rangle$ 
but it is not a direct factor.
More generally if $G=H\oplus K$ then every element of $K$ commutes with $h$ so $K \subset H$ making $G=H$